# making a Flyout within a MenuFlyout in XAML UWP C#

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Im trying to make a program with a settings button that opens a MenuFlyout which has a SubItem That opens a Flyout (notice that its a Flyout and not a MenuFlyout).
For some reason the code completely ignores all of my Flyout's properties and all of it's items.
This is my Current Code (just the Flyout part):

```
<Button x:Name="bar_settings" Content="Settings" Margin="10,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Roboto">
            <Button.Flyout>
                <MenuFlyout Placement="BottomEdgeAlignedLeft">
                    <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Change Money Symbol">
                        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                            <Flyout">
                                <Grid Width="100" Height="100"> // ignores
                                    <TextBlock Text="test123"/> // ignores
                                </Grid>
                            </Flyout>
                        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>
```

Here is what happens when I try to run the program and test the Flyouts:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to document [FlyoutBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyout?view=winrt-22621#examples), `FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout` and `FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout` need to be used together, but `MenuFlyoutSubItem`  has no event available to use `ShowAttachedFlyout`.

You can try the following solution, add `MenuFlyoutItem` in `MenuFlyoutSubItem`, then add your Grid in `MenuFlyoutItem.Template`.

```
<Button x:Name="bar_settings" Content="Settings" Margin="10,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Roboto">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout Placement="BottomEdgeAlignedLeft">
            <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Change Money Symbol">
                <MenuFlyoutItem>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
                                <TextBlock Text="test123"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                </MenuFlyoutItem>                     
            </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

Comment: well now the items in the last flyout cant be named. i give it the x:Name property but the code acts like it doesn't exists.
from my testing of trying to fix it it seems like its happening only with the items in the last flyout.
I think that its because its creating the items once I open them in the program itself